# How to add multiple item buy from Paypal new SDK

Tags: android

I am integrating PayPal new SDK. I have successfully integrate new SDK in my code. Single item successfully done. But I want to multiple item than how to integrate.

```
public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {
    PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("100.0"), "USD", "hipster jeans");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL);

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current support is not available by paypal mobile sdks. I did query on github paypal forum, you can verify here : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/30

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks R.J. I will be careful next time while answering.

Comment: @R.J That link doesn't provide a whole lot of information (it's simply says it's not supported), so this post is probably fine as is. @ user2914683 Remember that [so] is intended to be a resource of useful content, so it's usually good to [edit] your applicable posts if you find yourself with a less-than-ideal post (but, as mentioned above, it probably doesn't really apply here).

Answer (score 1):

With the updated SDK, you can specific  more items this way:

```
PayPalItem ppi1 = new PayPalItem("Item 1", 1, new BigDecimal(100.0), "USD", "Pid1");
PayPalItem ppi2 = new PayPalItem("Item 2", 1, new BigDecimal(100.0), "USD", "Pid2");
PayPalItem[] ppis = new PayPalItem[]{ppi1, ppi2};

// this is optional, for specifing extra costs
PayPalPaymentDetails pd = new PayPalPaymentDetails(
    PayPalItem.getItemTotal(ppis), // price
    new BigDecimal(10.0), // shipment costs
    new BigDecimal(0) // taxes
);

PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(
    new BigDecimal(210.0), "USD", "Item 1 and 2", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
payment.items(ppis);
payment.paymentDetails(pd);

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Translated for Android from the iOS demo :)